# Computationally verifying the equivalence of ridge regression estimates and Bayesian regression estimates

Tags: regression, bayesian, computational-statistics

I'm trying to show that the numerical estimates of ridge regression's parameter estimates are the same as the MAP parameter estimates of a Bayesian regression model with normal prior distributions. So far I have not been able to achieve numerical agreement.

I'm just toying with the mtcars data.

Ridge estimates:

```
> library(MASS)
> fit_ridge <- lm.ridge(mpg ~ cyl + hp + disp + wt,
+ data = mtcars,
+ lambda = 1)
> fit_ridge
                      cyl           hp         disp           wt 
39.133455180 -1.070747007 -0.019314307  0.003855685 -3.255577449
```

Bayesian model fit:

```
> library(rstanarm)
> fit_bayes <- stan_glm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + disp + wt,
+                       family = "gaussian",
+                       data = mtcars,
+                       prior = normal(0, 1),
+                       algorithm = "optimizing",
+                       prior_aux = NULL,
+                       prior_intercept = NULL)
+ > summary(fit_bayes)

Model Info:

 function:     stan_glm
 family:       gaussian [identity]
 formula:      mpg ~ cyl + hp + disp + wt
 algorithm:    optimizing
 priors:       see help('prior_summary')
 observations: 32
 predictors:   5

Estimates:
            Median MAD_SD 2.5% 97.5%
(Intercept) 40.3    2.5   35.5 45.2 
cyl         -1.2    0.6   -2.3 -0.1 
hp           0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0 
disp         0.0    0.0    0.0  0.0 
wt          -3.7    0.9   -5.5 -2.0 
sigma        2.3    0.3    1.8  3.0
```

Clearly there is some disagreement between the parameter estimates. Is my model specification incorrect? Or my understanding that these distinct estimators ought to be numerically the same?

Comment: those bayes estimates are medians, not maxima....

Comment: Are they? I specified `algorithm = "optimizing"` which I thought yields the posterior modes. https://mc-stan.org/rstanarm/reference/rstanarm-package.html

Comment: wondering if the ridge is also penalizing the intercept, but you set prior_intercept to null - this means flat prior for intercept right?

Comment: Correct, flat priors on the intercept and sigma in the Bayesian model.

Comment: is the ridge regression not ridging the intercept?

Comment: lm.ridge does not penalize the intercept if it is present in the model.

Comment: @probabilityislogic I have been able to show the methods produce the same point estimates numerically

Comment: I suspect your issue is that the canned routines (lm.ridge and glmnet) are first normalising your variables (which impacts the size of coefficients)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to show numerical agreement using stan (instead of rstanarm) and my own matrix math (instead of lm.ridge or glmnet). The stan model is

$$y \sim N(X\beta, \sigma^2_e)$$
$$ \beta \sim N(0, 1/\lambda) $$

which is implemented with the stan code:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> n;
  int<lower=0> p;
  matrix[n, p] mat;
  vector[n] y;
  real<lower=0> lambda;
  real<lower=0> sigma_e;
}

parameters {
  vector[p] beta;
}

model {
  // ridge prior on beta
  beta ~ normal(0,  sqrt(1/(lambda)));
  // likelihood model
  y ~ normal(mat * beta, sigma_e);
}
```

The MAP is given by :

```
out <- optimizing(stan_fit,
                  data = list(mat = Xmat,
                              n = nrow(Xmat),
                              p = ncol(Xmat),
                              lambda = lambda,
                              sigma_e = 1,
                              y = y))
```

where `Xmat` is the fixed effects design matrix and `y` is a vector of responses.

The ridge estimator is given by

```
ridge_beta <- solve(t(Xmat) %*% Xmat + lambda * diag(ncol(Xmat))) %*% t(Xmat) %*% y
```

I'm assuming that $\sigma_e$ is a known constant.

In the examples I've tried, the resulting MAPs and ridge point estimates agree.

Edit: This shrinks the intercept coefficient too.